# Try catch loops

Tags: java

I am not asking anyone to do my work I just need a little help solving this mismatch. This is my program:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
class FibonacciNumbers {

    FibonacciNumbers()          //default constructor
    {
    }

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int fOf(int n)
    {

        if (n == 0)                        //the base case
        {

            return 0;

        }
        else if (n==1)
        {

            return 1;
        }

        else 
        {

           return fOf(n-1)+fOf(n-2); 
        }
        }

 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       FibonacciNumbers fNumbers = new FibonacciNumbers();    //creates new object

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
         int n = 0;
        boolean IsRepeat = true ;  
        boolean isQuit; 
        boolean checkException = false;

     isQuit = false;  

     while (!isQuit) 
     {


try {

    {

        System.out.print("Enter the number you want to convert to Fibanocci('q' to quit): ");


        n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("The Fibanocci number for "+n+" is: ");
        n = fNumbers.fOf(n);
        System.out.println(n);

        System.out.print("Do you want to run again? Press 'N' for No or anything else to continue: ");  

        userInput = in.next();  

       if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("N") )
          {  
              isQuit = true;
              System.out.println("Good-bye!"); 
           }  
        else 

         {  
        IsRepeat = true; 
         }
       }
    }

catch(InputMismatchException ex) {  
          userInput = in.nextLine();  

           if  ((userInput.charAt(0) == 'q') || (userInput.charAt(0) == 'Q') )  
             {  

                  isQuit = true; 
                  System.out.println("Good-bye!");  

             }  

           else {  
                 checkException = true;
                 IsRepeat = true;
                 System.out.println("Invalid entry, Try again!");
              }    
    }

    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)
         {
            n = in.nextInt();
             if  (n<0 || n>46) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter an integer that is greater than 0 but less than 46 :");
                            checkException = false;//sets boolean value to false, continues the loop


                        }
                      else
                          {
                            IsRepeat = true;   
                          }
    }
    }
}
}
```

I did everything I got everything to work but at this part it is not going as I want it to run:

```
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)
         {
            n = in.nextInt();
             if  (n<0 || n>46) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter an integer that is greater than 0 but less than 46 :");
                            checkException = false;//sets boolean value to false, continues the loop


                        }
                      else
                          {
                            IsRepeat = true;   
                          }
    }
```

When I run it if the user inputs higher than 46 or lower than 0 then ask them for a different input but it is just doing the math. It wont do as i wrote the program.

Comment: How do you expect it to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? You're not using arrays in your code. Why do you even bother basing your application logic on exceptions? It's needlessly complicated.

Comment: Do you know what I could put instead of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @user2059140 simply check if the number falls outside of the desired range (1-46) and if it does, print a message and continue the loop.

Comment: @syb0rg from my Comp. Science teacher.

Comment: each language has some recommended formatting standard. This style is similar to what some C/C++/C# programmers use. Here's a document on [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws a "java.lang.StackOverflowError" instead of an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

The better way would be to catch an invalid input at

```
System.out.print("Enter the number you want to convert to Fibanocci('q' to quit): ");
n = in.nextInt();
```

you could set the "n = in.nextInt();" into a do - while- loop,

like:

```
do {
    ask for number
} while (check if number is correct);
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say. Do i put `System.out.print("Enter the number you want to convert to Fibanocci('q' to quit): ");
        
      
        n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("The Fibanocci number for "+n+" is: ");
        n = fNumbers.fOf(n);
        System.out.println(n);`   in a do loop and the rest in the while loop?

Comment: It is only one loop. The part between the "{"  and "}" will be repeated, as often as the part between "(" and ")" is true. So if you use" do { System.out.print("Enter the number you want to convert to Fibanocci('q' to quit): "); n = in.nextInt();} while (n < 0 || n > 46);" it will keep asking for a number until it is between 0 and 46 (both inclusive)